# /var/log/Xorg.0.log file growing fast

Tags: xorg

log file growing fast with below repeated error message - any help to stop this recurring message

```
[  1034.498] (WW) RADEON(0): flip queue failed: Invalid argument
[  1034.498] (WW) RADEON(0): Page flip failed: Invalid argument
[  1034.618] (WW) RADEON(0): flip queue failed: Invalid argument
[  1034.618] (WW) RADEON(0): Page flip failed: Invalid argument
[  1034.636] (WW) RADEON(0): flip queue failed: Invalid argument
[  1034.636] (WW) RADEON(0): Page flip failed: Invalid argument
```

Comment: You best shot would be to report this as a bug here https://bugs.freedesktop.org but they would require you to add some more details probably.  It is a problem with xorg/driver of your graphics card. Here is something similar: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97025  but there are many more. Have you tried with wayland instead of xorg? Or with the opensource or 3rd party driver (depending on what you use now)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify you are using the 7.10 radeon driver by issuing the following commands:

```
lshw -c video
modinfo radeon | more
```

If you see the following in the lshw/modinfo output, you are using the radeon driver:

Example of 1st lines of lshw:

```
 *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: RV516/M64-S [Mobility Radeon X2300] **or some other radeon card**
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
```

Example 1st lines of modinfo (kernel version may be different):

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    ATI Radeon
```

Verify that you are using the radeon driver.

If so, verify the version of `xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04` you are using.  Execute:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep radeon-hwe
```

The following should be displayed:

```
xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:7.10.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

This is the 7.10 radeon driver.

If all of the above is true for your machine, then this issue has a workaround:

Download the 7.9 radeon driver Ubuntu package (`xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04_7.9.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb`) from:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04/1:7.9.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1

Execute the following commands on the downloaded .deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04_7.9.0-0ubuntu1_16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-mark hold xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04
```

This downgrades the radeon driver package to version 7.9, fixes dependencies, and holds the driver pkg from further updates.

Upon reboot, issue should be resolved.

A bug has been reported to Freedesktop at:

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105217

The 7.9 radeon driver will need to stay held until the issue is fixed in:

`xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04`

I believe this issue to be a duplicate of:
[Blank screen with only mouse pointer after 7.10 radeon driver update; display does not switch to tty7 upon lightdm start; Xorg.0.log quickly grows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006610/blank-screen-with-only-mouse-pointer-after-7-10-radeon-driver-update-display-do)

Comment: Thank you, above radeon driver downgrade is working and log file is stable.

Comment: Nice!  You must be running simialr h/w to me...  ATI Radeon RV515/516.  The developers tell me the bug is unique to a small set of h/w.