# Blank screen with only mouse pointer after 7.10 radeon driver update; display does not switch to tty7 upon lightdm start; Xorg.0.log quickly grows

Tags: xorg, display, radeon, amd-graphics, mesa

*UPDATE 2/23/18*

This issue stems from the 7.10 version of the Freedesktop radeon driver.

A workaround to the issue is to downgrade to the 7.9 version of the driver.  Details of the investigation and workaround steps are below.

The primary symptom of the issue is a continous stream of warning messages in the Xorg.0.log, which keeps growing.

The warning messages look like:

```
[  4800.851] (WW) RADEON(0): flip queue failed: Invalid argument
[  4800.851] (WW) RADEON(0): Page flip failed: Invalid argument
```

*HISTORY*

I performed a normal upgrade on 2/15/18 through the software manager in 16.04LTS.

It upgraded the following libraries (`/var/log/dpkg.log [pkg][old ver][new ver]`):

```
libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-ubuntu0~16.04.1
libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libegl1-mesa:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libegl1-mesa:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libgbm1:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libgbm1:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libosmesa6:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libosmesa6:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libgles2-mesa:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libglapi-mesa:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libglapi-mesa:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
libxatracker2:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
linux-firmware:all 1.157.15 1.157.16
mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 17.2.4-0ubuntu1~16.04.4 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1
xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04:amd64 1:7.9.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 1:7.10.0-1~16.04.1
xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04:amd64 1:7.9.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 1:7.10.0-1~16.04.1
```

I should note, this is *not* the compiz/unity update package list.  It is the mesa drivers.

Upon reboot, I started getting a blank screen with only a mouse pointer when the display manager started.

I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go into console, and I can find the following in the `Xorg.0.log`:

```
[  4800.851] (WW) RADEON(0): flip queue failed: Invalid argument
[  4800.851] (WW) RADEON(0): Page flip failed: Invalid argument
```

These warning messages are *constantly* streaming into the log file, and it *keeps growing*.  This wasn't present before the library update.

Video h/w on my laptop:

```
 *-display

   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: RV516/M64-S [Mobility Radeon X2300]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:16 memory:d0000000-d3ffffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d8300000-d830ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

1st lines of modinfo output:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    ATI Radeon
```

I could really, really use some help here....  THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

*UPDATE 2/16/18:*

I appear to be booting to the wrong VT display.  All of the symptoms above are true; however, if I perform a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (up to <kbd>F6</kbd>) at startup and then immediately perform a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, which switches the VT, I go to my normal desktop as if it had booted correctly.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> without first going to console does not do anything.  So, this simplifies things somewhat as it now looks to be a config issue.  Lightdm seems to start Xorg on the wrong display.  I tried a vt.handoff=7 on the linux kernel command line, and this did not help.

Here is the output of `w` immediately after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and going to the normal desktop:

```
 09:38:01 up 44 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.60, 0.67, 0.82
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
user1    tty7     :0               08:53   44:14   6:16   0.29s /sbin/upstart -
```

This display listing appears normal.

I should note that compiz and unity still seem to function.  The desktop is fully available and already loaded when I switch to tty7.

*UPDATE 2/19/18:*

I don't believe this to be a duplicate of the compiz/unity issue.  The issue I observed resulted from the radeon driver update (7.9->7.10) on the morning of 2/15/18.  The compiz/unity update has yet to be applied to my system.  In fact, there is one other post that looks to be the same issue as I am seeing, it is: [/var/log/Xorg.0.log file growing fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006264/var-log-xorg-0-log-file-growing-fast)

The warning string in the `Xorg.0.log`, `flip queue failed`, is found in the following driver:

```
/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
```

found in package:

```
xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04
```

Specifically, the source file:

```
./src/drmmode_display.c:    xf86DrvMsg(scrn->scrnIndex, X_WARNING, "flip queue failed: %s\n",
```

Line 3093 in the source code of `drmmode_display.c`:

```
flip_error:
    xf86DrvMsg(scrn->scrnIndex, X_WARNING, "flip queue failed: %s\n",
           strerror(errno));

error:
    if (drm_queue_seq)
        radeon_drm_abort_entry(drm_queue_seq);
    else if (crtc)
        drmmode_flip_abort(crtc, flipdata);
    else {
        abort(NULL, data);
        drmmode_fb_reference(pRADEONEnt->fd, &flipdata->fb, NULL);
        free(flipdata);
    }

    xf86DrvMsg(scrn->scrnIndex, X_WARNING, "Page flip failed: %s\n",
           strerror(errno));
```

I logged this as: `[Bug 1750393] Blank screen with only mouse pointer after mesa driver update; display does not switch to tty7 upon lightdm start; Xorg.0.log quickly grows` on Launchpad.

Comment: This does **not** seem like a duplicate of 02/15/18 Unity Desktop Removed after update

Comment: Retracted the close vote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2/15/18 compiz update broke unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006621/2-15-18-compiz-update-broke-unity)

Comment: To downgrade mesa in order to problems you might want to see this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults See the section on downgrading mesa.

Comment: Thank you to WinEunuuchs2Unix for the downgrade suggestion.  That is on my "todo" list, but, I think I'll chase the logs for a few more days before downgrading.  This "feels" like an issue in the radeon driver, and I might be able to poke around and find something more useful.  Someone will want this fixed in mesa 17.2.8 since 17.2.4 was found to cause a similar issue on intel gpus.

Comment: Also, it could be an issue with the display configuration after the upgrade.  I'm going to dig more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify you are using the 7.10 radeon driver by issuing the following commands:

```
lshw -c video
modinfo radeon | more
```

If you see the following in the lshw/modinfo output, you are using the radeon driver:

Example of 1st lines of lshw:

```
 *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: RV516/M64-S [Mobility Radeon X2300] **or some other radeon card**
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
```

Example 1st lines of modinfo (kernel version may be different):

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    ATI Radeon
```

Verify that you are using the radeon driver.

If so, verify the version of `xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04` you are using.  Execute:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep radeon-hwe
```

The following should be displayed:

```
xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,now 1:7.10.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

This is the 7.10 radeon driver.

If all of the above is true for your machine, then this issue has a workaround:

Download the 7.9 radeon driver Ubuntu package (`xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04_7.9.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1_amd64.deb`) from:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04/1:7.9.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1

Execute the following commands on the downloaded .deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04_7.9.0-0ubuntu1_16.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-mark hold xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04
```

This downgrades the radeon driver package to version 7.9, fixes dependencies, and holds the driver pkg from further updates.

Upon reboot, issue should be resolved.

A bug has been reported to Freedesktop at:

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105217

The 7.9 radeon driver will need to stay held until the issue is fixed in:

`xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04`